# Using Hölder condition to find upper bound on Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, holder-spaces

First I want to stress that I don't want an answer, perhaps a hint. Let $f(x)$ have period $2\pi$ and let $|f(x) -f(y)| \leq c|x-y|^{\alpha}$, for some constants $c$ and $\alpha$ for all $x$ and $y$. How is that $$|a_n| \leq \frac{c\pi^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}, \qquad |b_n| \leq \frac{c \pi^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}$$

---

We have $$|a_n|  = \frac{1}{\pi} \left |\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx \right| \leq \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)||\cos nx| dx.$$

I can't apply the Hölder condition to the function $f(x)\cos nx$. Since $f$ has period of $2 \pi$, the upper bound on $|f(x) -f(y)|$ must be $c\pi^{\alpha}$ by selecting the maximum and minimum values of $f$ and noting they must be within $\pi$ of each other. I'm not sure how to link the two.

Comment: Let $t=\pi/n$. Then $\cos(nx)=-\cos(n(x+t))$; hence $a_n=\frac1\pi\int -f(x)\cos(n(x+t))\,dx=-\frac1\pi\int f(x-t)\cos(nx)\,dx$. Now if $A=B$ then $A=(A+B)/2$...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x) - f(x-t)| \cos nx dx $?

Comment: I get $\frac{4}{2 \pi n} \frac{c \pi^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}$ but since the first term is less than 1 it still holds?

Comment: NO, what you say you get is impossible. Can't tell what you did wrong...

Comment: Well $a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x) - f(x-t)) \cos nx dx$. Then I used the absolute values in the original question and the Holder condition which is $|f(x)-f(x-t)| \leq c|x-(x-t)|^{\alpha}$, which when replaced with $t = \pi/n$ gives the fraction. Integrating $|\cos nx|$ gives $4/n$.

Comment: sorry the integral of $|\cos nx |$ is just 4. I'm still not sure what's incorrect though. If I say $\cos \leq 1$, then the integral is just $2 \pi$ which cancels with the $2 \pi$ outside the integral.

Comment: Based on your last message I don't know why you think there's something wrong - the extra $1/n$ has gone away, right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the solution outlined by David C. Ullrich in comments:

Let $f_\delta(t) = f(t-\delta)$, a translation of $f$.

Thanks to the Hölder continuity of $f$, we have $\sup|f-f_\delta|\le C\delta^\alpha$. Hence, for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the Fourier coefficients satisfy $|\widehat{f}(n)-\widehat{f_\delta}(n)|\le C\delta^\alpha$.

On the other hand, $\widehat {f_{\pi/n}}(n) = -\widehat{f}(n)$ because translation by $\pi/n$ amounts to changing the phase of this particular frequency to the opposite one. (In mathematical terms this is the antiperiodicity of cosine and sine.)

Together, the above imply that $|\widehat{f}(n)|\le M(\pi/n)^\alpha$, where $M=C/2$.